Missing thermostat connections and wires
Inside my thermostat only 2 wires are connected,red to R and white to W—along with jumper wire to RC/O-RH/Brb. Behind the wall plate, two wires are just there not connected; Green and brown. I’ve attached the green to G and the fan came on. But there’s is no terminal for Brown and I don’t wanna mess anything up. What is this brown wire for? I been here for a few months and it’s never been a reason to turn on ac or heat. Heat works with jumper wire…but not sure if ac works. Is this just miscolored bc there’s no yellow wire and I understand that to be for Y (cooling)? 8-slot terminal C-Y-R-G-W-RC/O-RH/B. The very first terminal is blank

what is the model of thermostat and the AC, what type of heat do you have, gas, oil, electric, what jumper wire

A thermostat with only two wires hooked up ordinarily is for heating only. Does your system have air conditioning? Have you checked the other end of the thermostat cable to discover how the colors are connected to the furnace?

Can you post photos of the wiring at your furnace or air-handler please?

The letters indicate the following: G - Fan, Y - Cooling, W - Heat, C - Common, R - Power, Rh - Power heat, Rc - Power cooling, O-B-O/B - Heat pump.

Note that wire colour does not indicate what the wire does. You actually have to trace the wire back to the furnace (or other intermediary device) to see what it is connected to (if at all). If it isn't, you can use it for whatever purpose you want.
